# Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type

Tags: typescript, react-native, object, indexing, undefined

I am trying to convert a function from Javascript to Typescript but I keep running into the following error:

*Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type*

I understand that undefined cannot be used as an index, but I have tried the null check for the index type as well as conditional rendering but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code:

> useState hook of values I am using for the function

```
const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    companyName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    id: ""
  });

const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
```

> function which is essentially taking the newUser initial values, making a copy of that object, then calling setNewUser to populate the fields entered by the user into a newUser copied object.

```
const setValues = (propName?: number, value?: any) => {
        const cloneUser = { ...newUser };
        cloneUser[propName] = value;
        setNewUser({ ... cloneUser });
        setErrorMessage("");
  }
```

My main issue is the **`cloneUser[propName]`** cannot be undefined and used as an index and I'm not sure how to get around this.

Comment: I guess its because `propName` is optional in your `setValues` function.

Comment: @DavidScholz once I remove the ? from propName I get the following error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; companyName: string; email: string; password: string; id: string; }'.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Answer

Redefine the `setValues` function as:

```
const setValue = (propName: keyof typeof newUser, value: string) => {
  // your update code here
}
```

The parameter types are changed to match your state type, which is inferred as:

```
{
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  companyName: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  id: string;
}
```

### Alternatively

Specify the type for state:

```
type User = Readonly<{
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  companyName: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  id: string;
}>;

// in the component
const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState<User>({
  // initialize here
});
```

and define the function as:

```
const setValue = (propName: keyof User, value: string) => { ... }
```

## Explanation

The `propName` cannot be a `number | undefined`, since it is used to index an object with `string` keys (your state). It has to be a `string`.

The problem that you are facing is caused by the `propName` parameter defined as `propName?: number`.

This `(propName?: number, value?: any) => { ... }` is equivalent to `(propName: number | undefined, value: any | undefined) => { ... }`. This means that in your `setValues` function `propName` could be undefined, which is correctly detected as an error, as `undefined` value cannot be used to index an object.

### Suggestions

I would also suggest to change the name of the function to `setValue`, as you are only setting one given property at the time.

Additionally, you are setting string values, so the value can also be non-optional and typed as `string`.

Comment: I just redefined the function as `const setValue = (propName: string, value: string) => {` but now I am receiving this error => 
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; companyName: string; email: string; password: string; id: string; }'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; companyName: string; email: string; password: string; id: string; }'.`

Comment: Hey @melly18, thanks for pointing this out!

I updated my answer, as I had overlooked this. The issue was that the inferred type of your state did not contain a `string` index signature. TypeScript pointed this out by disallowing an arbitrary `propName` being passed that would not match the state properties.

The solution is to use a `keyof` operator and point it either to `typeof newUser` or a separately defined type for your state, e.g. `User`

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you. It made more sense conceptually to use: `const setValue = (propName: keyof typeof newUser, value: string) => {`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to arbitrarily add a key value pair to this object with a numeric key and any value. You need to tell typescript that this is allowed by defining a type, and passing it to the generic parameter of `useState`.

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mpdukw?file=App.tsx

```
type User = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  companyName: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  id: string;
  [key: number]: any; // This lets you add a numeric key with any value
};
```

```
  // generic parameter defines the type of `newUser`
  const [newUser, setNewUser] = useState<User>({
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    companyName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    id: '',
  });
```

Then, it doesn't make sense to allow an undefined key, so make that property mandatory:

```
  const setValues = (propName: number, value?: any) => {
    setNewUser({ ...newUser, [propName]: value });
    setErrorMessage('');
  };
```

---

Depending on the use case, you may want to allow an undefined key and just skip steps in that case.

```
  const setValues = (propName?: number, value?: any) => {
    if (propName) setNewUser({ ...newUser, [propName]: value });
    setErrorMessage('');
  };
```